# Non-Repeating jQuery Each Behavior

Tags: javascript, settimeout, jquery

Weird conceptual question.  The array below contains three elements.  When I run this code, my intention is that the script waits two seconds, shows an alert, waits two seconds, shows an alert, waits two seconds, and shows a final alert.  Instead, it just waits two seconds, and then shows all three alerts back to back to back.  I've been fooling around with it for a while, but can't find what I'm missing.  Any suggestions?

```
      $.each(node_array, function(index,value){
        if(value != undefined){
          setTimeout(function(){
            alert("hey")},
          2000)
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase your delay by 2 seconds per iteration.

```
$.each(node_array, function(index,value){
    if(value != undefined){
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert("hey");
        },(index+1)*2000)
    }
});
```

setTimeout is non-blocking, so code will continue to run before the delay has passed, resulting in you firing off x setTimeout's all at the same time with the same delay, so they all finish at the same time.

Comment: That's an idea, but if you're not fast enough there would be no delay between the alerts.

Comment: In my opinion that just demonstrates why alerts shouldn't be used for debugging.

Comment: On that I surely agree. It was painful to build that demonstration. But the delay due to the user reading and clicking the alert is similar to other delays (for example ajax requests or events).

Answer (score 3):

When you iterate, you set the timeout but you don't stop the iteration. So all the setTimeout are launched at the same time.

What you need is to launch the next `setTimeout` after the user clicked the alert :

```
var i=0;
function onestep(){
   alert('hey');
   var value = node_array[i];
   if (++i<node_array.length) setTimeout(onestep, 2000);
}
onestep();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/J53uE/)